# Обобщенное экземплярное свойство. Что это и зачем нужно?

Tags: c#, .net

Наткнулся в книжке CLR via C# на такой код:

```
public int this[string s]
{
    get { return 0; }
    set { }
}
```

Comment: Индексаторы изучаете?

Comment: Это что, викторина что ли? Неужели рядом с этим кодом не было что-нибудь написано?

Comment: не знаток c#, но что здесь обобщением называется? надо полагать, не дженерики, а просто что индексный доступ без указания имени свойства обобщением зовется?

Comment: [Использование индексаторов](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/using-indexers) (как раз пример с  `[string s]`)........  в целом что такое [Индексаторы](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В оригинале CLR via C#, Fourth Edition это

```
// Instance parameterful property (indexer)
```

Экземплярное свойство, принимающее параметры (индексатор)

"Обобщенность" - это артефакт перевода.

Что характерно, в переводе второго издания было

```
// Параметризованное свойство экземпляра
```

А вот 3-е издание было переведено заново, причем ужасно криво, с выбрасыванием частей оригинала, опечатками и полным искажением смысла некоторых кусков.

С тех пор перевод, судя по всему, так и остался ужасным, искажающим смысл и совершенно нечитабельным. И именно этот кривой перевод теперь считается одной из стандартных книг в списке для чтения начинающих C# разработчиков.

Comment: Может быть, оставьте замечание о кривом переводе в тексте списке литературы?

Comment: @VladD да, стоит добавить "читать в оригинале". Но альтернативы то нет. 2-е издание устарело, а новые переводят на основе 3-го.